# Add new line after words matching a specific pattern

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I'm trying to add a new line before and after a hyphenated word (one or many hyphens) in Notepad++

Input

```
This is a search-and-replace test which I need-help to figure-out</h2>
```

Output

```
This is a
search-and-replace
test which I
need-help
to
figure-out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you:

In Notepad++ press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and enter

Find:

```
(\w+(-\w+)+\s+)|(\w+(-\w+)+[^\r\n])
```

Replace:

```
\r\n\1\r\n
```

(need to match that word on the end with \r\n)

Comment: that regex yields the desired output. Maybe you have another output in mind?